# Force apt-get to prompt yes/no

Tags: apt

Is there a way to force `apt-get` to display yes/no prompt? A `--force-yes` option exists, but there seems to be no `--force-prompt` or similar option. If you attempt to install a package that has all dependencies already installed, it will begin installation without displaying a yes/no prompt. This can be bothersome if you want to review whether dependencies exist and which ones will be installed because you don't know if the potential dependencies are installed ahead of time.

NOTE: [When does “apt-get install” ask me to confirm whether I want to continue or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70651/29398) is somewhat related in that it describes under what standard conditions the prompt is displayed. I'm interested to know how to force it though.

Comment: "This can be bothersome if you want to review whether dependencies exist and which ones will be installed." I'm confused by this. If no dependencies are being installed, what are you reviewing?

Comment: Interesting question. There seems to be no way to do this, short of patching `apt-get` with a suitable option. However, this hypothetical option does not seem very useful to me, frankly.

Comment: @FaheemMitha My purpose for doing this is that it's a lot easier to find out what new dependencies could/will be installed using `apt-get install` rather than `apt-cache showpkg`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's just no way to do this with the current implementation of apt-get, you would need to open a feature request and appeal to the maintainer. The current behavior of apt-get is that when the list of packages you explicitly requested to be installed is the same as the list of packages that will get installed, and no other packages are affected with upgrades or breaks, **apt-get presumes the user already is sure of what is going to be done**, if you are not sure or want to analyze what will be done without actually installing the package, you can use [Costas recommendation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164470/41104) of `-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act`.

There are other tools like apt-listbugs that would analyze the versions of packages to be installed before you actually install them (in this case for bugs) and warn you.

Answer (score 9):

The command assume `yes` just in case of installing **one package** (which initiated from command line) AND **all dependencies in** the system already i.e nothing to install except one asked package.

In other word "if nothing to see (no extra packages) then no prompt (nothing to ask for)".

For testing purposes you can use a key `-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act`

Comment: @cpburnz if `all dependecies are installed` already you will **not** been promted so any other packages will not been installed.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, I can see, but in similar situation now. **Usually** I do use `sudo aptitude install -P PACKAGE_NAME`, what always ask before install. However now in Debian default package manager is `apt|apt-get` and it does not have this functionality. Of course I can still install `aptitude` and use it... However I have wrote small sh/bash wrapper function/script for `apt-get` to ask before installation. It is really raw and I wrote it as a function in my terminal.

```
$ f () { sudo apt-get --simulate install "$@" | grep -v '^Inst\|^Conf'; read -p 'Do You want to continue (y/N): ' ans; case $ans in [yY] | [yY][eE][sS]) sudo apt-get -y install "$@";; *);; esac; }
```

Now, let's make it more clear:

```
f () {
  # Do filtered simulation - without lines contains 'Inst' and 'Conf'
  sudo apt-get --simulate install "$@" | grep -v '^Inst\|^Conf';

  # Interact with user - If You want to proceed and install package(s),
  # simply put 'y' or any other combination of 'yes' answer and tap ENTER.
  # Otherwise the answer will be always not to proceed.
  read -p 'Do You want to continue (y/N): ' ans;
  case $ans in
    [yY] | [yY][eE][sS])
      # Because we said 'yes' I put -y to proceed with installation
      # without additional question 'yes/no' from apt-get 
      sudo apt-get -y install "$@";
    ;;
    *)
      # For any other answer, we just do nothing. That means we do not install
      # listed packages.
    ;;
  esac
}
```

To use this function as a sh/bash script simply create script file e.g. `my_apt-get.sh` with content (Note: listing does not contain comments, to make it a bit shorter ;-) ):

```
#!/bin/sh

f () {
  sudo apt-get --simulate install "$@" | grep -v '^Inst\|^Conf';
  read -p 'Do You want to continue (y/N): ' ans;
  case $ans in
    [yY] | [yY][eE][sS])
      sudo apt-get -y install "$@";
    ;;
    *)

    ;;
  esac
}

f "$@"
```

Then put it for e.g. in `~/bin/` and make it executable with `$ chmod u+x ~/bin/my_apt-get.sh`. If directory `~/bin` is included in your `PATH` variable, you will be able to execute it simply by:

```
$ my_apt-get.sh PACKAGE_NAME(S)_TO INSTALL
```

Please note:

- The code does use `sudo`. If you use `root` account, you probably need to adjust it.
- The code does not support shell autocompletion
- Have no idea how the code works with shell patterns (e.g. "!", "*", "?", ...)